# Make a whole DIV a transparent drop zone with fine-uploader

Tags: jquery, amazon-s3, fine-uploader

I have an `<article>` element in my web application which gets populated with content by Javascript code. I'd like to add the ability to drag-and-drop files over the currently visible portion of that `<article>` element (as it has a scrollbar) and get these files over to S3.

I have been testing fine-uploader with the provided `test.html`. My server-side code signing is working and I get the files into my S3 buckets.

My question is UI-related: how do I add the ability to drag-and-drop files over `<article>` and show an UI *only when the file has been dropped* to confirm the upload without moving all my HTML code into a fine-uploader template? I tried adding a `<div>` above the page, but this obviously interfere with my ability to select text in the `<article>` element placed below…

I feel I am missing something obvious. Essentially my question is similar to the **dropzone.js** solution here: https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/wiki/Make-the-whole-body-a-dropzone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't provide any files named "test.html".

Regardless, you can add as many drop zones as you want at any time via the [addExtraDropzone API method](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#addExtraDropzone).

For example:

```
uploader.addExtraDropzone(document.getElementsByTagName('article'));
```

Comment: It didn't work as it is, but it eventually lead me to the example at the bottom of that page: http://docs.fineuploader.com/features/drag-and-drop.html, which does what I need (at least for my first iteration).The `test.html` I was mentioning is the example at the bottom of the page http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/quickstart/02-setting_options-s3.html

Comment: For the most part, there is really no good reason to use the jquery wrapped version of Fine Uploader.  That's why I included a non-jquery example.